# Changing the colour of 'string' in Gedit when typing C++

Tags: gedit

I'm using Gedit to write C++ code, and have applied my custom syntax colour scheme which works (and looks) great with the exception of the `string` type, which, for both my custom style and the various bundled styles, is the same colour as the rest of the text. I am able to access the xml files that contain the style settings and there is no setting for defining the colour of `string`. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution. It's not in the style file, but deeper into the Gedit infrastructure in the language definition file instead. These files are store in `/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/` and the file in question is cpp.lang. Look for the list enclosed called `id = "keyword"` and add to this list the entry `<keyword>string</keyword>`, save the file, and restart Gedit. Done.

Comment: The `string` class was added in C++ and does not exist in C, so you probably shouldn't add it to the C file. Also the reason that it wasn't highlighted specially is that, unlike int or char, it's not a keyword - just the name of a class.

Comment: I've taken your advice and moved the edit to `cpp.lang` instead and edited my response appropriately. I think this come down to personal taste, as `string` is indeed the name of a class, but the syntax is used in much the same way as other declarations, when I've posted code to Stack Overflow, `string` has been highlighted there, so like I said, personal preference.

Comment: It's highlighted on stackoverflow because stackoverflow highlights all languages the same and in some languages `string` is a keyword. And I'm not saying you shouldn't highlight string (though I personally would find it inconsistent if `string` is highlighted, but e.g. `vector` is not) - I'm just explaining why gedit doesn't.

Comment: What if I don't have access to the .lang file? How do I extend the lang file to add more keywords?